# Are there hotels where children are not allowed?

Tags: hotels, children

Are there hotels that don't accept children?

I must admit that this question is a case of reverse psychology. I am more interested in the opposite. Children tend to raise quite some emotions with many, where even annoying bragging businessmen or smelly animals are well accepted. So I would very much like to be able to point people with "childphobia" to existing hotel chains where there is a no-child policy.

Comment: I think the question needs to be more specific, where do you want child free hotels?

Comment: I hope that [love hotels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_hotel) don't accept children! BTW, do you think [tag:discrimination] would be a suitable tag for this question?

Comment: @Andrew Despite the name, "love hotels" are not only used for sex, there are many other under-24h-stay uses.

Comment: Searching for resorts in Baleares, I've encountered quite a few adult-only, no children allowed. Not any particular chain though.

Answer (score 16):

How about Sandals resorts?  Couples only--that certainly excludes kids!

Edit:  Why is someone objecting to this answer?  The question was whether there were hotels that didn't accept children, I provided a very clear example of such:  A chain of hotels that only accepts couples.

Comment: but the OP wants to say to any child-objectors: "go stay at X if you don't like my kids" and a resort in the caribbean isn't exactly nearby to some city-based hotel where this potential objecting might be.

Answer (score 10):

You can actually find a list of Adult Only resorts on [this page](http://www.resortvacationstogo.com/specialties/adults-only_resorts.html).  The only difference between them is what is considered adult but it's either 16+ or 18+.

Comment: I am not sure, but adult-only sounds to me something different then being child free ;)

Comment: @Andra I guess I see your point.  Depends on what you mean by child too. :)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can find a lot of hotels like this just searching for "[child free hotel](http://www.google.com/search?q=child%20free%20hotels&oq=child%20free%20hotels)".

Answer (score 4):

In the US, I doubt any chain hotel can refuse children because there are laws prohibiting discrimination against families. Normally, this is seen in residential housing. Only senior retirement communities can restrict minors to short visits.

You might be able to find resorts that have segregated areas or facilities with adults-only hours. Some bed-and-breakfasts might also unofficially restrict patrons to adults, but they're probably walking a thin line.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this law prohibiting discrimination against families? Because plenty of resorts are violating it, and I'm wondering if it's not what you think?

Comment: I think you're right; that it's only for permanent housing ("family status"), but it would likely still cause an uproar if the hotel wasn't a very high-end resort or a tiny B&B.

Comment: Wow, why not? If they have a pool inside of their premises without fence could be reason enough to disallow children. No-one wants to be responsible for a child that runs of and drowns.